# Safari 5 HTML Iframe not working properly with URL + Params

Tags: html, url, iframe, safari

I have an URL in IFRAME with parameters like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/id=123&place=123"></iframe>
```

Works perfectly on FF3+, IE6+ (believe in me) and Safari 4, but in Safari 5 is different. S5 changes the URL to http://www.example.com/id=123 **&amp;** place=123

Someone knows how can I do a workaround to solve this headache?

tks.

Comment: Where do you see this change?

Comment: You *must* have `&amp;place`, or it's simply invalid HTML. The browser will parse that `&amp;` and turn it into a normal ampersand in the attribute value before using it as a URL.

Comment: @bobince Yes. Sometimes I forgot that HTML is not so different from XML. Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean it changes the URL? Does it try and access the url `http://www.example.com/id=123&amp;place=123`? Or does it still try and access `http://www.example.com/id=123&place=123`? When I try your example pointing to `localhost` instead of `example.com`, and record the request from Safari 5, I get the ampersand `&`, not `&amp;`

```
$ nc -l 4242
GET /?id=123&place=123 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4242
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.1 Safari/533.17.8
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Referer: http://livedom.validator.nu/blank.html
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Note that using `&amp;` in the URL in your source is actually the correct way to write it; if you write `&`, browsers will try to interpret the following text as an entity. If it cannot find a matching entity, then it will assume that you incorrectly used a raw `&` and will use that, but you need to be careful because you could accidentally form an entity instead of the actual ampersand you were requesting. So, to avoid possible mistakes, you actually should write `&amp;` in your code. If you are inspecting or serializing the DOM, such as through `innerHTML`, Safari may be rewriting the URL for you to correctly use `&amp;`, to avoid this sort of error.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Maybe, the &amp; isn't the problem. I tried in my localhost passing an URL with parameters and works too, even I changing the domain (appointing to 127.0.0.1). In my real case, I'm putting an external HTTPS address with a valid certificate in Iframe and it fails. If I put the same URL in address bar, it works. I not am sure if safari is handling correctly iframe addresses, it's an atypical behavior.

Comment: In iframe, the external address has the same behavior of no parameters passed.

Comment: @manoelhc You're going to have to provide us with some more information in order to be able to help you. Can you provide the `https` URL which fails? Can you provide us with the headers you are seeing sent back from the server? It's possible that the site is doing something to try and block being loaded in an `<iframe>`, such as `X-Frame-Options:` http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/09/08/x-frame-options/ , which might be causing you problems on newer browsers.

Comment: Thanks Brian again. I figured out the "problem". The URL that I use in this Iframe, makes a redirection to another page. By default, Safari 5 is setted to accept cookies just from the "pages that I visit", so, in theory, I'm not visiting the page inside the iframe. I was totally wrong about blaming &amp; for this problem. I think that I don't have another choice to solve this, but guide the user to enable cookies for every page. Right?

Comment: @manoelhc That might be your only option; I don't know much about workarounds for that issue. You might try asking another question about that issue, or Googling for "safari iframe cookies" or something similar. From a quick search, it looks like there might be a workaround by doing a POST from within the iframe, but I can't guarantee that it will work.

Comment: Best provide a non-iframe-based normal link as backup for users who don't accept third-party cookies (which is more than just Safari users).